# Reset Fiddler UI Layout?

Tags: fiddler

Is there a way to reset the Fiddler UI to the default layout, getting rid of any adjustments I have made? I am experiencing an issue where the Rule Editor is partially hidden when I add a rule in AutoResponder. It looks like if I could just adjust the size of the rule editor, that would fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold the `shift` key as you start Fiddler to reset the layout to the default. Fixed it for me.